# Chrome version 32 drop-down fade in / out

Tags: google-chrome, drop-down-menu

Since Google Chrome version 32 all of the default drop-down-menus now fades in and out.

Is there an option to disable this behaviour?

- In my browser for all websites
- For my website (probably with css) for other Chrome v32 users

Edit: [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/49MXF/)

```
<select><option value="A">jsFiddle Placeholder</select>
```

Edit2: It seems like there's another bug. When opening a drop down menu and selecting the last item, it doesn't get highlighted, although when clicking it selects it.

Comment: added an example, you have to use chrome 32 of course

Comment: Not a fan of this new chrome feature.  Seems a little clunky on different machines... just venting ha ha..

Comment: God its awful. A new usability problem on a drop-down heavy page. WTF is Chrome thinking? "We won't fix font rendering, we need to add crappy animations first". Grr.

Comment: I have tried without luck: -webkit-transition-duration, -webkit-transition-timing-function, -webkit-animation-timing-function, -webkit-transition-property, -webkit-transition

Comment: Thanks, Daw. I hope we can get this figured out soon, it's quite awful.

Comment: is this a windows thing? I'm using version 33 here on OSX and (thankfully) there are no animated menu items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems fixed with Version 34.0.1847.116 m

Answer (score 1):

To disable it for yourself you need to disable visual themes. To do this...

> **Right click the Chrome icon on your Windows Desktop**
>
> Click Properties
>
> Select the Compatibility Tab
>
> Check "Disable Visual Themes" (Click OK to acknowledge)
>
> You're done. The next time you start Chrome from the Desktop, the scroll will function just >as before.
>
> **If you have Chrome pinned to the task bar or Start menu**,
>
> then instead of 1. and 2. , you'll >have to:
>
> a) Right click on the pinned Chrome icon
>
> b)Then again right click on "Google Chrome" (just on top of the option "Unpin this program >from ...")
>
> Click Properties.

https://superuser.com/questions/704736/cant-use-scrollbars-of-dropdowns-html-select-in-chrome-32/704737#704737

Comment: Unfortunately this option no longer exists in Windows 8... Either way, this shoudn't be the way to "fix" this problem.

Comment: Indeed, I wish browsers would use the same inputs and selects. It makes it a nightmare to create consistent styled forms. Good luck finding a solution, I thought -webkit-appearance or similar might knock it back to the old dropdown but alas not.

Comment: For me, on windows 7, this did not disable the fade in effect. I only get some random rendering errors in the main window when the close/maximise/minimise buttons are not rendered correctly (or rendered twice), no change on dropdowns in a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to disable it currently on windows 8, however a number of bug reports have been opened up on chromes bug tracker. The more people that star an issue, the faster it will be addressed.

If you would like this fixed sooner, I suggest you star the following.

[Chrome is ignoring my Windows menu fade preferences and using a fade animation on dropdowns](http://crbug.com/334737)

[Animations on Drop Down interfere with RDP connections](http://crbug.com/339845)